# Refreshing old XHR Header

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I just came across a scenario were I need to refresh the xhr header for ajax calls. Here is the scenario,

Let's say I loaded the page by making an ajax call with one of the custom xhr header holding value "abc". If I close the page and reopen it (using ctrl + shift + T in case of chrome) the page makes the server side call with same xhr header with value "abc".

Is there a way I can change that value to something else so that when I reopen the page the xhr header has a different value.

Just curious!
Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Where is the value for the header being read from?

Comment: From client side. JS file.

Comment: So what keeps you from changing the value when a new page is loaded?